# Swift generic class parameter implementing another parameter

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I want to implement a generic class in Swift that takes two parameters. The one required constraint is that first parameter is a protocol and second one must implement this protocol.

Code:

```
protocol Protocol {}

class Generic<T: Protocol, U>  where U: T {

}
```

Compiler error says:

> error: type 'U' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'T'

but this is not really true, as `T` is a protocol.

Do you have an idea how to implement that?

Comment: If the first parameter **is** a protocol then it's not generic. In your example the first parameter is a generic which is constrained to `Protocol`.

Comment: try implementing the protocol as `protocol Protocol: class {}`

Comment: I do not believe this is expressible in the Swift type system. `T` is not a protocol; it is a type that implements `Protocol` (which can't be a protocol at all; protocols do not implement their parents, nor do they implement themselves even though you would think they would). There is no way to express "protocol that inherits from another protocol" and there's no way to express "type parameter that is a protocol." You'll need to discuss the underlying problem you're trying to solve; this isn't the right approach.

Comment: As I understand your type constraints, you want `T` to implement `Protocol`, and want `U` to implement everything that `T` implements. Hence, `U == T`, or not? Therefore, you do not need `U`, you could simply use `T` everywhere. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, you're right. `T` is just something that implements `Protocol`, it can be class as well. I missed that.

Answer (score -1):

I *think* what you want is

```
protocol Protocol {} 
class Generic<T: Protocol> {
    init(type: T.Type, instance: T) {

    } 
}
```

but a use case would help us understand what you're trying to achieve...